# Adding a NSMutableArray to project & access that same NSMutableArray in another class

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, nsmutablearray

I am having some trouble trying to share a `NSMutableArray` of Strings to another class. I have a `tableView` that is populated with `Strings` that I would like to add to a `NSMutableArray`. Then use that SAME `NSMutableArray` in another `ViewController`

I have created a class with the subclass of `NSMutableArray`

**.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface HYServicesMArray : NSMutableArray

@property (nonatomic, weak)NSMutableArray * arrServicesUserChoice;


@end
```

**.m**

```
#import "HYServicesMArray.h"

@implementation HYServicesMArray

@dynamic arrServicesUserChoice;


@end
```

I am trying to add elements to this `NSMutableArray` from a `tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`

**.m**

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSLog(@"You have selected: %@",cell.textLabel.text);

    // add cell.textLabel.text to arrServicesUserChoice 
    // Tried the code below but causes my app to crash  
      arrServicesUserChoice = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
      [arrServicesUserChoice addObject:cell.textLabel.text];
}
```

[image]

How ever I am unable to add elements to the `arrServicesUserChoice`. I am stuck please help! Thank you in advance!

Comment: I dont see any code that adds data to array

Comment: @Mr.T:

` arrAvaialbleServicesList = [[NSMutableArray init]alloc];` `[arrAvaialbleServicesList arrayByAddingObject:cell.textLabel.text];`

Comment: please add the code to the question.

Comment: also add what issue u r facing...do u get any crash? is array nil after adding ?

Comment: check my answer @Jay

Comment: @Mr.T - please see comment attached to your answer

Comment: Why is your property `weak`? Make it `strong` and see where that gets you.

Comment: @ChrisH - tried it but still running into the same issue

Comment: @JayDave how do u create the object HYServicesMArray in the UITableView class?

Comment: @Ostanik, subclass of NSMutableArray

Comment: Sorry @JayDave i think you don't understand my question, in your UITableView class, you have that object "arrServicesUserChoice" how do you declared it. To access the "arrServicesUserChoice" you have to create a instance of  HYServicesMArray correct?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3862619/should-i-subclass-the-nsmutablearray-class

please check

Answer (score 1):

YOu declared a mutable array, and the code you used to add returns an array, but it dont add anyting. you have to add the objects like:

```
     [arrAvaialbleServicesList addObject:cell.textlabel.text];
```

After this, your mutable array will have the added data

or you can declare another array, and do it your way"

```
 NSArray *test=[arrAvaialbleServicesList arrayByAddingObject:cell.textLabel.text];
```

after this, the new array will have the array with added data.

Comment: I am unable to add, `addObject:` - my build crashes saying "No visible @interface for 'NSArray' declares the selector 'addObject:'"

Comment: make sure "arrAvaialbleServicesList" is NSMUTableArray but not NSArray

Comment: arrAvaialbleServicesList is in fact a NSMutableArray

Comment: did you try doin [NSMutableArray alloc]init] ? @JayDave

Comment: Thank you, that has stopped my app from crashing - however I still do not have access to `addObject:` with my [arrAvaialbleServicesList addObject:cell.textLabel.text];

Comment: thats strange. can you check it your array is nil or not after you add the object?

Comment: also post the code of where you declared the arrAvaialbleServicesList array.

Comment: I have added a picture to show my entire code where I am setting up my TableView. also my array is null

Comment: see in your view did load, you are giving NSARray to NSMUtableARRay

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90564/discussion-between-jay-dave-and-mr-t).

Answer (score 1):

I think you should change

```
@dynamic arrServicesUserChoice;
```

To

```
@synthesize arrServicesUserChoice;
```

Answer (score 0):

The original initialization to MutableArray does nothing really and does not specify arrAvalabelServiceList as Mutable - arrayByAddingObject creates a brand new instance which is NSArray, NOT NSMutableArray

```
  arrAvaialbleServicesList = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
  [arrAvaialbleServicesList arrayByAddingObject:cell.textLabel.text];
```

You are however not assigning this new instance to anything, if you did:

```
arrAvaialbleServicesList = [arrAvaialbleServicesList arrayByAddingObject:cell.textLabel.text];
```

You would at least get a handle to the new NSArray instance.

What you should probably to is to create your list when you setup the table:

```
arrAvaialbleServicesList = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
```

The on your didSelect you would just add the text to the list:

```
NSString *selected = [NSString stringWithString:cell.textLabel.text];

[arrAvaialbleServicesList addObject:selected];
```

or something close to this then you would add something to your list whenever you select a row in the table.

Comment: Still running into the issue of `[arrAvaialbleServicesList addObject:selected];` does not have access to `addObject:`

Answer (score 0):

What you try to create is a kind of public static var correct? i think the better way to do that is creating an Class that can handle your MutableArray object. Doing her as a singleton class is a good way to guarantee that you will not create another instance of your object and lost your MutableArray. Here is a sample:

HYServicesMArray.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface HYServicesMArray : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *arrServicesUserChoice;

+ (HYServicesMArray *) instance;

@end
```

HYServicesMArray.m

```
#import "HYServicesMArray.h"

@implementation HYServicesMArray

+ (HYServicesMArray *)instance
{
    static HYServicesMArray *_ServicesMArray = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        _ServicesMArray = [[self alloc] init];
    });
    return _ServicesMArray;
}


-(id)init {
    self.arrServicesUserChoice = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    return self;
}

@end
```

And the application on your didSelectRowAtIndexPath method:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSLog(@"You have selected: %@",cell.textLabel.text);

    [[HYServicesMArray instance].arrServicesUserChoice addObject:cell.textLabel.text];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should make it `@synthesized` and dereference the property as `self.arrServicesUserChoice`. (You can leave the `self` away only in Swift.)

This should compile:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSLog(@"You have selected: %@",cell.textLabel.text);

    self.arrServicesUserChoice = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [self.arrServicesUserChoice addObject:cell.textLabel.text];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to declare it `@dynamic`, You need to `@synthesize` it. If you don't want to `@synthesize` it then use **self**. You can check the difference between here between these two here.

[@synthesize vs @dynamic, what are the differences?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1160498/synthesize-vs-dynamic-what-are-the-differences)
If you want to use this same array in another class then you should declare a property in that class and pass this class's array to another class using segue.