# Swift: subclass NSMutableArray

Tags: arrays, swift, nsmutablearray

I'm trying to subclass `NSMutableArray` in Swift to provide bridge functionality for a Swift array to some old Objective-C codebase. However, I can't find a functional example and all my attempts have failed so far. This is the closest I got to a functional example:

```
import UIKit

class MyArray: NSMutableArray {

    var array: [Int]?

// Adding an initializer triggers the error: 'required' initializer 'init(arrayLiteral:)' must be provided by subclass of 'NSArray'
//    override init() {
//        self.array = []
//        super.init()
//    }

    static func makeArray() -> MyArray {
        let array = MyArray()
        array.array = []
        return array
    }

    override var count: Int {
        get {
            if let count = array?.count {
                return count
            }

            return 0
        }
    }

    override func insert(_ anObject: Any, at index: Int) {
        print("insert called")
    }

    override func removeObject(at index: Int) {
        print("removeObject called")
    }

    override func add(_ anObject: Any) {
        print("Trying to add \(anObject)")
        if let newInt = anObject as? Int {
            array?.append(newInt)
        }
    }

    override func removeLastObject() {
        print("removeLastObject called")
    }

    override func replaceObject(at index: Int, with anObject: Any) {
        print("replaceObject called")
    }
}

func append42(array: NSMutableArray) {
    array.add(42)
}

let myArray = MyArray.makeArray()

print("Before: \(myArray.array)")
myArray.array?.append(42)
// The following two lines generate a SIGABRT
//myArray.add(42)
//append42(array: myArray)
print("After: \(myArray.array)")
```

However, using the `add` method always triggers a `SIGABRT`. I'm using XCode 12.4 on Catalina.

EDIT (for clarifications): I know that Swift bridges `Array`s to `NSArray`s. However, I need to pass a reference to a Swift array to some Objective-C code accepting an `NSMutableArray` and possibly making updates to the array.

Essentially I'm adding some Swift code to an existing project, and I'd like to use Swift typed arrays in the new code, but I still to pass these arrays to the old code. I know that I can make an `NSMutableArray` copy of the Swift array, pass this copy to the old code, then copy it back to the Swift array but it's rather convoluted and hardly maintainable. What I'm tried to do is encapsulating a reference to a Swift array into an 'NSMutableArray' subclass so I can transparently use this subclass with the legacy code.

Comment: The idea of that `array` property in `NSMutableArray` subclass doesn't quite make sense. If you really don't want Swift value semantics of copying the Swift `Array` to a `NSMutableArray` (which, FWIW, is immaterial in most cases), I'm wondering why you don't just use `NSMutableArray` directly, e.g., `let values: NSMutableArray = [1, 2]`. And you can do `values.add(42)` and pass it as a parameter to your Objective-C method, too. Clearly, you lose a lot of benefits of Swift generic `Array` types, but that comes with using old ObjC API and insisting on reference semantics.

Comment: I might suggest sharing more information about the Objective-C API and the nature of the arrays with which you are dealing, and we might be able to offer better counsel...

Comment: I edited the original post with some additional details. The idea is to avoid copying a Swift `array` to an `NSMutableArray` and back every time I need to call some legacy function.

Comment: @Rob Of course I could just use an `NSMutableArray` in Swift, but I would lose the benefits of Swift typed `Array`s. Again, what I'm trying to do is to provide a transparent bridge from Swift `Array` to `NSMutableArray` (similar to what Apple provides from `Array` to `NSArray`). Encapsulating a reference to a Swift `Array` seemed to be the most logical choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you [aware](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/imported_c_and_objective-c_apis/working_with_foundation_types) that:

> When importing the Foundation framework, the Swift overlay provides value types for many bridged reference types. Many other types are renamed or nested to clarify relationships.

And specifically that :

> Class clusters that include immutable and mutable subclasses, like NSArray and NSMutableArray, are bridged to a single value type.

So you can use `Array` in place of `NSArray` and if you want a `NSMutableArray` is also a Swift `Array` (but a `var`).
Same thing applies for `Dictionary` and `NSDictionary`.

#### Disclaimer

I would probably not use that in production code and although sublassing `NSArray` and `NSMutableArray` is not forbidden, documentation says :

> There is typically little reason to subclass NSMutableArray.

And this should be reason enough to consider another solution IMHO

#### Edit

After reading this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3873129/1425697)

I decided to check `NSMutableArray` [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsmutablearray):

> Methods to Override
>
> NSMutableArray defines five primitive methods:
>
> insert(_:at:)
>
> removeObject(at:)
>
> add(_:)
>
> removeLastObject()
>
> replaceObject(at:with:)

> In a subclass, you must override all these methods. You must also override the primitive methods of the NSArray class.

So I checked `NSArray` [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsarray) too:

> Any subclass of NSArray must override the primitive instance methods count and object(at:). These methods must operate on the backing store that you provide for the elements of the collection. For this backing store you can use a static array, a standard NSArray object, or some other data type or mechanism. You may also choose to override, partially or fully, any other NSArray method for which you want to provide an alternative implementation.

and now, with:

```
@objc class MyArray: NSMutableArray {

    var array: [Int] = []
    static func makeArray() -> MyArray {
        let array = MyArray()
        array.array = []
        return array
    }

    override var count: Int {
        array.count
    }
    
    override func object(at index: Int) -> Any {
        array[index]
    }

    override func insert(_ anObject: Any, at index: Int) {
        print("insert called")
        if let newInt = anObject as? Int {
            array.insert(newInt, at: index)
        }
    }

    override func removeObject(at index: Int) {
        array.remove(at: index)
        print("removeObject called")
    }

    override func add(_ anObject: Any) {
        print("Trying to add \(anObject)")
        if let newInt = anObject as? Int {
            array.append(newInt)
        }
    }
}

func append42(array: NSMutableArray) {
    array.add(42)
}
```

I have :

```
let myArray = MyArray.makeArray()

print("Before: \(myArray.array)")
myArray.array.append(42) // [42]
// The following two lines generate a SIGABRT
myArray.add(42) // [42, 42]
append42(array: myArray)
print("After: \(myArray.array)")

// Before: []
// Trying to add 42
// Trying to add 42
// After: [42, 42, 42]
```

#### Fun facts

- I tried your code in a playground and reproduced the crash. I tried in a `XCTestCase` and it did not crash
- calling `super.add(_:)` in `add(_:)` will trigger `insert(_:at:)`
- `NSMutableArray` conformance to `ExpressibleByArrayLiteral` is probably written in an extension (which makes perfect sense since `NSMutableArray` is an Objective-C class) and so overriding `init()` [forces](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Initialization.html#ID231) you to override `init(arrayLitteral:)` and the compiler says *Overriding declarations in extensions is not supported*. :

> Automatic Initializer Inheritance
>
> Rule 1
>
> If your subclass doesn’t define any designated initializers, it automatically inherits all of its superclass designated initializers.
>
> Rule 2
>
> If your subclass provides an implementation of all of its superclass designated initializers—either by inheriting them as per rule 1, or by providing a custom implementation as part of its definition—then it automatically inherits all of the superclass convenience initializers.

Comment: Yes, I know that Swift bridges Arrays to NSArray. However, I need to pass a Swift array to an Objective-C function accepting an NSMutableArray. I also know I can make an NSMutableArray copy from a Swift array, however I need a reference to the same array, not a copy.

Comment: It might have been a good idea to say so in your question. It was a bit too long for the comment section :)

Comment: I edited the original post with some additional details.

Comment: Well I linked the doc and it does say "There is typically little reason to subclass NSMutableArray". I agree with you and I upvoted your comment, I also love puzzles and *maybe* OP has a **really** good reason

Comment: I will update my answer ASAP to add a disclaimer. In the mean time I'm not sure I understand your argument about OCP. Would you care to elaborate ? My understanding was that since subclassing is permitted (though discouraged) `NSMutableArray` was open to extension. My main concern would have been about LSP. https://www.dzombak.com/blog/2015/05/Cocoa-s-mutable-subclass-pattern-is-an-antipattern.html.

Comment: I didn't see your edit before I posted the same exact solution!

Comment: Oh too bad, it means that you saw it too late :)

Answer (score 1):

We should generally follow the Open-Closed Principle, OCP, namely that classes are open for extension and closed for modification. This attempt to subclass `NSMutableArray`, and replace a few key methods, violates OCP. It is likely to manifest all sorts of weird behaviors.

If you really want to subclass, you will want to override all of the primitive methods of both `NSArray` and `NSMutableArray`. Theoretically you could examine your Objective-C code and see what methods it is calling, but this is a very fragile approach. I would not advise this pattern.

Personally, if I was trying to integrate with some Objective-C code that required `NSMutableArray`, I would stick with Swift arrays and create a `NSMutableArray` before I called my Objective-C library, and then copy it back to an array (consistent with the value semantics of Swift arrays).

Consider:

```objectivec
@implementation Foo
- (void)bar:(NSMutableArray *)array {
    [array addObject:@42];
}
@end
```

I would shim this for a Swift `Array`:

```swift
extension Foo {
    func bar(_ values: inout [Int]) {
        let array = NSMutableArray(array: values)
        bar(array)
        values = array as! [Int]
    }
}
```

Then I could do:

```swift
var values = [1, 2]
values.append(3)
let foo = Foo()
foo.bar(&values)
print(values)                       // 1, 2, 3, 42
```

But I would avoid avoid subclassing `NSMutableArray` simply because I happened to be calling some Objective-C routine that used `NSMutableArray`. I would only do that if benchmarking (or other considerations) deemed that absolutely necessary.

---

Let us assume for a second that you absolutely needed to stick with `NSMutableArray` (e.g., you had millions of records and are calling this Objective-C routine constantly). In that case, I still would not advise subclassing `NSMutableArray`, but rather just use `NSMutableArray` directly in my Swift code. If I wanted to retrieve `Int` values from my `NSMutableArray` and didn't want to cast all over the place, I'd add an `extension` to `NSMutableArray`:

```swift
extension NSMutableArray {
    func append(integer value: Int) {
        add(value)
    }

    func intValue(at index: Int) -> Int {
        return self[index] as! Int
    }
}
```

Then you could do:

```swift
let values: NSMutableArray = [1, 2]
values.append(integer: 3)

let foo = Foo()
foo.bar(values)

print(values)                       // 1, 2, 3, 42

let value = values.intValue(at: 3)
print(value)                        // This is `Int` value of 42
```

Now, I know this is not the answer you were hoping for, namely that you did not want to “lose the benefits of Swift typed `Array`s” while still using this Objective-C legacy code. But at least these two methods give you type-safe setting and retrieval of integer values.

Comment: I was about to comment on your answer quoting Apple's documentation on subclassing `NSMutableArray`, and I discovered the issue! For some reason, I missed that to subclass `NSMutableArray` you also have to override `object(at:)` from `NSArray`, not just `count`. So, thank you for pointing me in the right direction.