# NSMutableArray - force the array to hold specific object type only

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsmutablearray

Is there a way to force NSMutableArray to hold one specific object type only?

I have classes definitions as follow:

```
@interface Wheel:NSObject  
{    
  int size;  
  float diameter;  
}  
@end  


@interface Car:NSObject  
{  
   NSString *model;  
   NSString *make;  
   NSMutableArray *wheels;  
}  
@end
```

How can I force **wheels** array to hold **Wheel** objects only with code? (and absolutely not other objects)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there any way to enforce typing on NSArray, NSMutableArray, etc.?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/649483/is-there-any-way-to-enforce-typing-on-nsarray-nsmutablearray-etc)

Answer (score 101, accepted):

**Update in 2015**

This answer was first written in early 2011 and began:

> What we really want is parametric polymorphism so you could declare, say, `NSMutableArray<NSString>`; but alas such is not available.

In 2015 Apple apparently changed this with the introduction of "lightweight generics" into Objective-C and now you can declare:

```
NSMutableArray<NSString *> *onlyStrings = [NSMutableArray new];
```

But all is not quite what it seems, notice the "lightweight"... Then notice that the initialisation part of the above declaration does not contain any generic notation. While Apple have introduced parametric collections, and adding a non-string *directly* to the above array, `onlyStrings`, as in say:

```
[onlyStrings addObject:@666]; // <- Warning: Incompatible pointer types...
```

will illicit the warning as indicated, the type security is barely skin deep. Consider the method:

```
- (void) push:(id)obj onto:(NSMutableArray *)array
{
   [array addObject:obj];
}
```

and the code fragment in another method of the same class:

```
NSMutableArray<NSString *> *oops = [NSMutableArray new];
[self push:@"asda" onto:oops]; // add a string, fine
[self push:@42 onto:oops];     // add a number, no warnings...
```

What Apple have implemented is essentially a hinting system to assist with automatic inter-operation with Swift, which does have a flavour of type-safe generics. However on the Objective-C side, while the compiler provides some extra hints the system is "lightweight" and type-integrity is still ultimately down to the programmer - as is the Objective-C way.

So which should you use? The new lightweight/pseudo generics, or devise your own patterns for your code? There really is no right answer, figure out what makes sense in your scenario and use it.

For example: If you are targeting interoperation with Swift you should use the lightweight generics! However if the type integrity of a collection is important in your scenario then you could combine the lightweight generics with your own code on the Objective-C side which enforces the type integrity that Swift will on its side.

**The Remainder of the 2011 Answer**

As another option here is a quick general subclass of NSMutableArray which you init with the kind of object you want in your monomorphic array. This option does not give you static type-checking (in as much as you ever get it in Obj-C), you get runtime exceptions on inserting the wrong type, just as you get runtime exceptions for index out of bounds etc.

This is *not* thoroughly tested and assumes the documentation on overriding NSMutableArray is correct...

```
@interface MonomorphicArray : NSMutableArray
{
    Class elementClass;
    NSMutableArray *realArray;
}

- (id) initWithClass:(Class)element andCapacity:(NSUInteger)numItems;
- (id) initWithClass:(Class)element;

@end
```

And the implementation:

```
@implementation MonomorphicArray

- (id) initWithClass:(Class)element andCapacity:(NSUInteger)numItems
{
    elementClass = element;
    realArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:numItems];
    return self;
}

- (id) initWithClass:(Class)element
{
    elementClass = element;
    realArray = [NSMutableArray new];
    return self;
}

// override primitive NSMutableArray methods and enforce monomorphism

- (void) insertObject:(id)anObject atIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
    if ([anObject isKindOfClass:elementClass]) // allows subclasses, use isMemeberOfClass for exact match
    {
        [realArray insertObject:anObject atIndex:index];
    }
    else
    {
        NSException* myException = [NSException
            exceptionWithName:@"InvalidAddObject"
            reason:@"Added object has wrong type"
            userInfo:nil];
        @throw myException;
    }
}

- (void) removeObjectAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
    [realArray removeObjectAtIndex:index];
}

// override primitive NSArray methods

- (NSUInteger) count
{
    return [realArray count];
}

- (id) objectAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
    return [realArray objectAtIndex:index];
}


// block all the other init's (some could be supported)

static id NotSupported()
{
    NSException* myException = [NSException
        exceptionWithName:@"InvalidInitializer"
        reason:@"Only initWithClass: and initWithClass:andCapacity: supported"
        userInfo:nil];
    @throw myException;
}

- (id)initWithArray:(NSArray *)anArray { return NotSupported(); }
- (id)initWithArray:(NSArray *)array copyItems:(BOOL)flag { return NotSupported(); }
- (id)initWithContentsOfFile:(NSString *)aPath { return NotSupported(); }
- (id)initWithContentsOfURL:(NSURL *)aURL { return NotSupported(); }
- (id)initWithObjects:(id)firstObj, ... { return NotSupported(); }
- (id)initWithObjects:(const id *)objects count:(NSUInteger)count { return NotSupported(); }

@end
```

Use as:

```
MonomorphicArray *monoString = [[MonomorphicArray alloc] initWithClass:[NSString class] andCapacity:3];

[monoString addObject:@"A string"];
[monoString addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:42]]; // will throw
[monoString addObject:@"Another string"];
```

Comment: +1 — based on this code I got the idea to use blocks to test, if a certain object should be added to an array. This can be a membership for a class, a value for a property of the object or virtual anything else. Please have a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8190530/does-objective-c-support-generics/8198852#8198852

Comment: @bendytree - using macros to generate one class per type for static typing checking is an interesting idea. However you don't need the forward invocation stuff at all, just subclass NSMutableArray properly as in the above example and it will be much more efficient. So combine your macros with the above and you'll get the best of both.

Comment: @CRD I am facing problem where I need to check if object to be added to array is implementing a delegate or not...

Comment: @Jignesh - You can use the same outline but instead of testing for class membership you'd be testing for protocol conformance or selector implementation. If that doesn't make sense post a question (not another comment).

Comment: Why do you still need a NSMutableArray realArray in your subclass. MonomorphicArray IS an NSMutableArray.. Can't you call the super method of the parent class ?

Comment: @PaulPraet - `NSArray` and `NSMutableArray` are a *class cluster* and the way they are designed any subclass must provide its own storage for the elements - which can be a separate instance of `NSArray`/`NSMutableArray` as used here. See "Subclassing Notes" in the [`NSArray`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html) documentation.

Comment: Reluctantly voting down since this answer is now outdated and incorrect. I hope OP changes the accepted answer.

Comment: @BenC.R.Leggiero - The answer isn't "incorrect", indeed if you want a monomorphic array the answer gives you that at runtime; while the new lightweight generics get you closer, but not all the way there, at compile time. Yes language changes means it is a bit "outdated" as it doesn't cover stuff that has happened since it was written, I've edited to add some details (as doing so has some merit in this case) but you'll often find stuff on SO whose veracity time has changed. If providing answers incurred editing in perpetuity there would be far fewer answers! There can be value in history. :-)

Comment: @CRD Thank you so much for providing the modern approach; I voted it back up! I agree there's value in history, but indeed answering on SO implies a dedication to ensuring your answer is up-to-date, since no one is allowed to ask a question that's already been asked, and your Google rank will likely only climb.

Answer (score 29):

Since Xcode 7, generics are available in Objective-C.

You can declare a `NSMutableArray` as:

```
NSMutableArray <Wheel*> *wheels = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:@[[Wheel new],[Wheel new]];
```

The compiler will give you a warning if you try to put non-Wheel objects in the array.

Comment: I think you've forgotten an `*` before wheels.

Comment: Don't I need to say `[[NSMutableArray<Wheel*> alloc] init...]`?

Comment: We might all want parametric types, unfortunately we need to read Apple's small print; these are what Apple term "lightweight" generics and essentially only exist as comments to assist the Swift compiler. They unfortunately do not always "give you a warning" if you attempt an ill-typed operation, I've updated my answer to provide some more detail.

Answer (score 10):

I could be wrong (I'm a noob), but I think, if you create a custom protocol and make sure the objects you are adding to the array follow the same protocol, then when you declare the array you use

```
NSArray<Protocol Name>
```

That should prevent objects being added that do not follow the said protocol.

Comment: Why answer this if you don't know it?

Comment: It's known as attempting to help fellow programmers.

Comment: This is wrong, this type allows you only to assign subclasses of NSArray that conform to `Protocol Name`. So it's related to the array object itself and not its contents. You should write `NSArray<id<Protocol Name>>` to achieve your initial goal.

Answer (score 5):

as per i know.. before you added any object in wheels mutableArray, u have to add some check mark. Is the object which i am adding is class "wheel". if it is then add, other wise not.

Example:

```
if([id isClassOf:"Wheel"] == YES)
{
[array addObject:id) 
}
```

Something like this. i dont remember the exact syntax.

Comment: I agree - don't subclass nsmutablearray - just hide it in your car, and make the only two methods addWheel:(Wheel*)aWheel and deleteWheel:. (for example).

Comment: When I say hide the wheel array, I mean make it private, don't make it a property, etc. You might also need a -(NSArray*)wheels; call, which does this return [NSArray arrayWithArray:wheels];

Answer (score 3):

I hope this will help (and work... :P )

**Wheel.h** file:

```
@protocol Wheel
@end

@interface Wheel : NSObject
@property ...
@end
```

**Car.h** file:

```
#import "Wheel.h"
@interface Car:NSObject  

{  
   NSString *model;  
   NSString *make;  
   NSMutableArray<Wheel, Optional> *wheels;  
}  
@end
```

**Car.m** file:

```
#import "Car.h"
@implementation Car

-(id)init{
   if (self=[super init]){
   self.wheels = (NSMutableArray<Wheel,Optional>*)[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
   }
return self;
}
@end
```

Comment: how to initialize wheels?

Comment: @JagveerSinghRajput here you go - I edited my answer for you :)

Answer (score 2):

Xcode 7 allows you to define Arrays, Dictionaries, and even your own Classes as having generics. The array syntax is as follows:

```
NSArray<NSString*>* array = @[@"hello world"];
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there's any way to do it with `NSMutableArray` out of the box.  You could probably enforce this by subclassing and overriding all the constructors and insertion methods, but it's probably not worth it.  What are you hoping to achieve with this?

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible; an NSArray (whether mutable or not) will hold any object type. What you can do is to create your own custom subclasses as already suggested by Jim. Alternatively, if you wanted to filter an array to remove objects that weren't of the type you want, then you could do:

```
- (void)removeObjectsFromArray:(NSMutableArray *)array otherThanOfType:(Class)type
{
    int c = 0;
    while(c < [array length])
    {
        NSObject *object = [array objectAtIndex:c];
        if([object isKindOfClass:type])
          c++;
        else
          [array removeObjectAtIndex:c];
    }
}

...
[self removeObjectsFromArray:array otherThanOfType:[Car class]];
```

Or make other judgments based on the result of isKindOfClass:, e.g. to divide an array containing a mixture of Cars and Wheels into two arrays, each containing only one kind of object.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the nsexception if you dont have the specific object.

```
for (int i = 0; i<items.count;i++) {
 if([[items objectAtIndex:i] isKindOfClass:[Wheel class]])
 {
  // do something..!
 }else{
  [NSException raise:@"Invalid value" format:@"Format of %@ is invalid", items];
  // do whatever to handle or raise your exception.
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's something I've done to avoid subclassing NSMutableArray: use a category. This way you can have the argument and return types you want. Note the naming convention: replace the word "object" in each of the methods you will use with the name of the element class. "objectAtIndex" becomes "wheelAtIndex" and so on. This way there's no name conflict. Very tidy.

```
typedef NSMutableArray WheelList;
@interface NSMutableArray (WheelList) 
- (wheel *) wheelAtIndex: (NSUInteger) index;
- (void) addWheel: (wheel *) w;
@end

@implementation NSMutableArray (WheelList)

- (wheel *) wheelAtIndex: (NSUInteger) index 
{  
    return (wheel *) [self objectAtIndex: index];  
}

- (void) addWheel: (wheel *) w 
{  
    [self addObject: w];  
} 
@end


@interface Car : NSObject
@property WheelList *wheels;
@end;


@implementation Car
@synthesize wheels;

- (id) init 
{
    if (self = [super init]) {
        wheels = [[WheelList alloc] initWithCapacity: 4];
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

Comment: While this works to give you the types it doesn't actually restrict the contents of the array to be the type as you can just call `addObject:` directly - which means a subsequent `wheelAtIndex:` could be casting something other than a wheel as a wheel and chaos will ensue. You can combine your approach with `MonomorphicArray` from the other answer; just extend `MonomorphicArray` with a class with typed getters and setters.

Answer (score 0):

protocol maybe a good idea:

```
@protocol Person <NSObject>
@end

@interface Person : NSObject <Person>
@end
```

to use:

```
NSArray<Person>*  personArray;
```

Comment: Have you test your code?? why NSArray conform Person protocol can do the check?

Comment: the compiler would only give a warning if your object did not conform to the protocol.

Comment: No, it won't, In fact you will get `Incompatible pointer types initializing 'NSArray<Person> *' with an expression of type 'NSArray *'`,even when you insert Person in it.

Answer (score 0):

There is one-header file project which allows this: 
**[Objective-C-Generics](https://github.com/tomersh/Objective-C-Generics)**

**Usage**:

Copy ObjectiveCGenerics.h to your project. 
When defining a new class use the GENERICSABLE macro.

```
#import "ObjectiveCGenerics.h"

GENERICSABLE(MyClass)

@interface MyClass : NSObject<MyClass>

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString* name;

@end
```

Now you can use generics with arrays and sets just as you normally do in Java, C#, etc.

**Code:**
[image]