# How to create a typed stack using Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, collections, stack, strong-typing

I can create a stack class quite easily, using push and pop accessor methods to an NSArray, however.  I can make this generic to take any NSObject derived class, however, I want to store only a specific class in this stack.

Ideally I want to create something similar to Java's typed lists (List or List) so that I can only store that type in the stack.  I can create a different class for each (ProjectStack or ItemStack), but this will lead to a more complicated file structure.

Is there a way to do this to restrict the type of class I can add to a container to a specific, configurable type?

Comment: possible duplicate of [NSMutableArray - force the array to hold specific object type only](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5197446/nsmutablearray-force-the-array-to-hold-specific-object-type-only)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this, although I do not recommend it:

```
@interface TypedMutableStack : NSObject {
   Class type;
@private
   NSMutableArray *internal;
}

- (id) initWithType:(Class) type_;

@end

#define CHECK_TYPE(obj) if(![obj isKindOfClass:type]) {\
      [NSException raise:NSInvalidArgumentException format:@"Incorrect type passed to TypedMutableStack"];\
 }


@implementation TypedMutableStack

- (void) dealloc {
  [internal release];
  [super dealloc];
}

- (id) initWithType:(Class) type_ {
   self = [super init];
   if(self) {
      type = type_;
      internal = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
   }
   return self;
}

- (void) addObject:(id) obj {
   CHECK_TYPE(obj);
   [internal addObject:obj];
}

- (void) replaceObjectAtIndex:(NSUInteger) index withObject:(id) obj {
    CHECK_TYPE(obj);
    [internal replaceObjectAtIndex:index withObject:obj];
}

- (void) insertObject:(id) obj atIndex:(NSUInteger) index {
    CHECK_TYPE(obj);
    [internal insertObject:obj atIndex:index];
}

//...
@end
```

Comment: This won't work; `NSMutableArray` and `NSArray` are abstract.  You can't subclass them and not provide your own storage mechanism.  The easy way to do this is to add an `NSMutableArray` ivar and forward on to that instead of to `super`.

Comment: Much better.  For consistency, I'd also throw an `NSInvalidArgumentException`, but that's just my style. :)  (no need to invent a new exception name that way)

Answer (score 3):

NSArray will take any object that implements the same protocol as NSObject; it doesn't need to be derived from NSObject. Because all dispatch in Objective-C is dynamic, inheritance isn't necessary for polymorphism.

Putting that aside, if you've implemented your own push and pop methods, you can easily test the incoming type using [isKindOfClass](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/isKindOfClass%3a) or [isMemberOfClass](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/isMemberOfClass%3a) and reject those of the incorrect type.

To go further down, [NSMutableArray](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html) documents which methods are conceptually primitive below the heading 'Subclassing Notes' in the Overview section at the top of the page. If you subclass NSMutableArray and alter addObject:, replaceObjectAtIndex:withObject: and insertObject:atIndex: to test the type of the incoming object then you can create a typed array.

Answer (score 1):

Objective-C doesn't have generics or templates. Hence, idiomatic Objective-C code is written using `NSObject *` and `id` everywhere, casting as necessary.

Whatever you want to do, you should model it on the existing frameworks. See how NSArray, NSDictionary, NSSet, etc., are implemented, and follow suit.