# Managing objects of different classes in a single NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, arrays, object, pointers

I'm looking for advice on whether or not this is a good practice. I apologize for the long form explanation. I have a large grid of x,y coordinates. The grid is occupied by objects of varying classes, all with different methods and data. When a user touches a grid coordinate, I'm looking for the cleanest way to route my program to the proper method, dependent on the object type.

I'll use shapes as an easy way to explain what I'm doing. Say I have 2 classes, Circle and Square both with a parent class of Shape.

I'm adding objects of Circle class and Square class to an NSMutableArray called shapeManager. When a user touches the grid I want to figure out the object type for that coordinate so I can route to the appropriate method.

```
for (Shape *shape in shapeManager) {

  if (shape.type == kCircle) {

    [self circleSelected:shape];

  }

}

-(void)circleSelected:(circle *)circle { }
```

Am I recasting the pointer as a different class when I do this? Are there any downsides to this? I'm just looking for a good way to handle a touch event on a grid, when the object that lives at that coordinate is unknown and of multiple possible classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The downside to your approach comes if you add another `Shape` - you end up having to change this code. The other approach is to add a method, say `userSelected`, to your `Shape` class and have each subclass override this method to do whatever is appropriate for the kind of shape they represent.

In this other approach your loop becomes:

```
for(Shape *shape in shapeManager)
   [shape userSelected];
```

And, for example, `Circle` gains a method:

```
@implementation Circle

// override Shape's userSelected and do what a circle needs to do
- (void) userSelected
{
   ...
}
```

Which approach you choose is up to you, there is no *right* answer *per se*, but object-oriented style usually favours the latter.

**Comment Followup**

To go from a child to a parent you do not need a cast, but can include one - this is a fundamental plank of inheritance-based object-oriented languages like Obj-C.

Going the other way, from parent to child, in Obj-C (a) requires a cast and (b) should be protected by a check - both because you don't know which, if any, of the children you have. In Obj-C (a) just tells the compiler you *think* you know and it should trust you, (b) is you checking to make sure!

You do (b) with `[<obj> isKindOfClass:[<classname> class]` which tests if `<obj>` is of type `<classname>` *or* any of its children; or you can use `isMemberOfClass` which tests if `<obj>` is of type `<classname>` *but not* any of its children. The former is more common to allow for easy expansion (e.g. you may start off with `Rectangle` being a `Shape` and later introduce `Square` being a `Rectangle`; a test for `isMemberOfClass:[Rectangle class]` would be `YES` for both `Rectangle` and `Square` while `isKindOfClass:[Rectangle class]` is only `YES` for `Rectangle`).

Explicit testing is commonly not required as method dispatch often subsumes it - as in `[shape userSelected]` above which will call the appropriate implementation of `userSelected` based on the actual type of `shape` at runtime. When explicit testing is required using tests and casts is the way to do it.

And yes, collections of mixed type are common, indeed they are another of the planks of inheritance-based object-oriented languages like Obj-C.

[Note: What Obj-C lacks which a number of other languages have is a way to limit what a collection may contain. E.g. an `NSMutableArray` can contain *any* object, while in your case it might be beneficial to be able to say `NSMutableArray of Shape` to limit it to just `Shape` and its subclasses. C#, Ada, and even C++ (in as much as it enforces anything) all provide this. If you need to you can do it yourself in Obj-C, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5197446/nsmutablearray-force-the-array-to-hold-specific-object-type-only).]

Comment: Thank you for your comments on the practice in general. Could you comment on the casting of objects to different classes? I'm having trouble finding any documentation on it.  Can you always simply cast an object back and forth to parent/child classes via the argument type? Is this a common way to manage many objects of different classes that are all derived from the same parent class?

Answer (score 0):

All classes that derive from `NSObject` inherit a method called `isMemberOfClass:` that will test for class membership using introspection.  You may find this useful for your purposes.

```
for (Shape *shape in shapeManager) {

    if ([shape isMemberOfClass:[Circle class]]) {   
        [self circleSelected:(Circle*)shape];
    }
    else if ([shape isMemberOfClass:[Square class]]} {
        [self squareSelected:(Square*)shape];
    }
}
```

There is also an `isKindOfClass:` method that does a similar test, but will also return true if the receiving object is a subclass of the class you are testing against.

Answer (score 0):

How about implementing 'selected' method in the subclasses of Shape, which are Circle and Square class. Then the object can call 'selected' method directly.

```
for (Shape *shape in shapeManager) {
    [self selected];
}
```

Circle implementation

```
@interface Circle: Shape
{
}
@implementation Circle
-(void)selected
{
    // do your circle select stuff here
}

@end
```

Square implementation

```
@interface Square: Shape
{
}
@implementation Square
-(void)selected
{
    // do your square select stuff here
}

@end
```