# How to check assignment since addObject doesn't access setter?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa, setter, getter-setter

I just noticed that calling `addObject:` on an NSMutableArray doesn't access that array's setter.

E.g., for NSMutableArray `self.myArray`, `[self.myArray addObject:object]` does not use `[self setMyArray:array]` to add the object.

Previously I have been using custom setters and getter to check assignment before assigning; e.g., if I wanted an array that only accepted objects of class `MyClass`, I would do the following:

```
- (void)setMyArray:(NSMutableArray *)myArray
{
    for (id object in myArray)
    {
        if (![object isKindOfClass:[MyClass class]]) return;
    }
    _myArray = myArray;
}

- (NSMutableArray *)myArray
{
    if (!_myArray) _myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    _myArray = myArray;
}
```

How do I go about achieving this same functionality when changing the array via `addObject:`, `removeObject:`, and other similar functions that may circumvent the setter?

Comment: "`[self.myArray addObject:object];` does not use `[self setMyArray:array];` to add the object." - oh wait, why should it? An array is not identical to the items it contains...

Comment: Perhaps you may observe any insertion or deletion.

Comment: @H2CO3 I had thought it was part of what defined an array, but I was mistaken. Makes sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally this kind of problem is the reason why `NSMutableArray` is usually avoided in preference of `NSArray`.

This is the simple solution, use NSArray instead of NSMutableArray:

```
self.myArray = [self.myArray arrayByAddingObject:foo];
```

However, if the array is really big that will cause performance issues. Then you've got two options:

- you can have your own `addObjectToMyArray:` method in your class and always use that
- you can create an `NSArrayController` and use that to access your array. It will implement key value observing and bindings and all of that stuff.

`NSMutableArray` is designed to perform `addObject:` with as few CPU instructions as possible and therefore does not proved any way for external code to be notified that the object was added. You have to have some other class wrapped around it.

Do not try to subclass `NSMutableArray`, because it is a "class cluster" making subclasses extremely complicated.

Comment: Yes, I learned that NSMutableArray subclassing is a class cluster%&$! back when I was first teaching myself Obj-C a few months ago :) Thankfully my current arrays are fairly small, but I'll be sure to use NSMutableArray when performance is more important than type-checking at assignment.

Comment: I just discovered that I already created a class called RestrictedMutableArray that possesses most of the features of NSMutableArray but allows setting a property `@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *allowedClasses`! The only thing it can't do is direct enumeration(?), i.e., instead of `for (id obj in restrictedMutableArray), you'll just have to do `for (int i = 0; i < restrictedMutableArray.count; i++)`. I'll upload it to GitHub once I clean it up a bit.

Comment: If you have time, you should look into NSArrayController as well.

Answer (score 0):

If what you wish to do is ensure objects in the array are of a particular class then [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5197446/nsmutablearray-force-the-array-to-hold-specific-object-type-only/5198040#5198040) to the question "NSMutableArray - force the array to hold specific object type only" provides code to do exactly that.

If you wish to do other checks on assignment then you can use the code in that answer as a starting point.