# How to write ObjectiveC selectors in commented out code and allow Xcode cross referencing

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

In regular code if I write something like:

```
[self performAnActionWithArg:myArg andThisArg:myArg2];
```

Then I can CMD click on "performAnActionWithArg:" and it will take me to the declaration of that method.

However, how can I reference a method within a comment to get xCode to perform the same cross linking behaviour? Is it even possible? I've tried lots of variations such as:

```
// See [MyClass performAnActionWithArg:myArg andThisArg:myArg2]
```

but xCode will not see performAnActionWithArg:andThisArg: as a method I can navigate to. Any ideas?

Comment: I think you are SOL.  However see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13751906/does-objective-c-have-an-equivalent-to-java-annotations  where some people talk about 3rd party products for methods annotation.  Perhaps that might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not by cmd-clicking but maybe by other means.

Xcode tries to recognize method names to make cmd-click work. You can see this because if you hold down the cmd key and hover over the method, the text is highlighted in blue, even in a comment. But in commented code Xcode can't use the compiler to work out the correct method name, so it often guesses the wrong text to highlight. For example, with this line:

```
Cell *cell = [cv dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:kCellID forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

Cmd-clicking works fine, but if I comment it out, the wrong text is highlighted:
[image: wrong highlighting]
Xcode tries to look up something named `dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:kCellID`, which doesn't exist, so it reports "symbol not found".

A comment that **only** contains the method name **almost** works:

```
// dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:forIndexPath:
```

But not quite, because Xcode misses the final `:`.

However if you select the entire method name and then right-click on it, one of the menu options is "jump to definition", which works:
[image: contextual menu]
This isn't nearly as convenient as cmd-click, but it works.