# How to print an object variables from a NSMutableArray?

Tags: ios, objective-c

From what I've read `NSMutableArray` adds objects.

How can I print the `Student` object variables from a given position without casting the object as a `Student`.

I'm looking for something like `ArrayList<Student>` in Java so i can easily print `ArrayList.get(i).getName`, `ArrayList.get(i).getPrice` .

```
    StudentRepository* myStudentRepo = [[StudentRepository alloc]init];

    Student* myStudent = [[Student alloc]init];

    myStudent.name = @"John";

    // add a Student to the NSMutableArray
    [myStudentRepo.studentRepository addObject:myStudent];

    NSLog(@"Value: %@", myStudentRepo.studentRepository);

    for(Student* myStudentItem in myStudentRepo.studentRepository)
    {
        NSLog(@"Value: %@", myStudentItem.name);
    }

    // print the Student from a given position
    NSLog(@"Value: %@", [(Student*)[myStudentRepo.studentRepository objectAtIndex:0] name]);
```

Comment: Thanks all for the help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you posted is fine as-is. There is no equivalent in Objective-C / Cocoa to Java's typed collections. You need to cast the results.

Actually, there is a little trick you can do:

```
NSLog(@"Value: %@", [myStudentRepo.studentRepository[0] valueForKey:@"name"]);
```

Comment: +1, Or it can be used as `[myStudentRepo.studentRepository[0] name]`. It shouldn't show any warning.

Comment: @ACB True since you end up calling `name` on an `id` object. As long as the compiler has seen a `name` method from somewhere, it will be happy.

Answer (score 1):

You can use KVC (Key Value Coding) to access the properties of an object without casting it:

```
[[myStudentRepo.studentRepository objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"name"];
```

See: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/BasicPrinciples.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002170-BAJEAIEE

Answer (score 1):

You could override `description` or `debugDescription` in you `Student` class:

Since I don't the make up of your student, please allow the following example of a straight forward way:

```
// could also be -(NSString*)debugDescription    
- (NSString *)description {
      return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Prop1: %@ \nIntVal1: %d\nfloatVal1 = %3.2f", self.prop1, self.intVal1, self.floatval1];
}
```

This gets tedious with large and complex objects, though.

Answer (score 1):

You Can use something like this

```
[(Student*)myStudentRepo.studentRepository[0] name];
```

Or you can override the description of the Student like this:
in Student.m add this :

```
-(NSString *)description{
        return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Student Name:%@", self.name];
     }
```

Whenever you need to print the Student just type:

```
NSLog(%@, student);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to ensure your collection actually only contains `Student` objects, the equivalent of Java's parametric collection you can do this. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5197446/nsmutablearray-force-the-array-to-hold-specific-object-type-only) for a solution for dictionaries, an array solution would be similar. You can combine the accepted solution to that question with typed getters & setters to avoid any casts.

Alternatively if you are not actually concerned over ensuring only `Student` objects can be added you can write an extension or category which adds a typed getter or setter - this just calls the standard setter or getter adding an casts as needed. You'll see this approach in the answers to the above question as well.

*(No code here as you'll find all you need in the other question.)*