# Monomorphic arrays with static type checking

Tags: objective-c

```
id<UIView> views = @[one, two, three];  
NSInteger object = [views lastObject]; // Compiler will warn me that `views` stores only UIViews
```

How far would I have to go implement this? Does anybody have some experience with extending clang to support similar features?

[Similar: nsmutablearray-force-the-array-to-hold-specific-object-type-only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5197446/nsmutablearray-force-the-array-to-hold-specific-object-type-only)

Comment: Wait. You're willing to extend the compiler...yourself?

Comment: The better solution is to dupe one of the many radars open for this to improve its chances of being added officially to the language (http://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=2731402 is one example). Modifying ObjC this way is really not something I would recommend one do independently.

Comment: You can't. The closest I've seen is [Typed Collections with Self Types in Objective-C](http://www.jonmsterling.com/posts/2012-02-05-typed-collections-with-self-types-in-objective-c.html).

Comment: PS `NSInteger` is not an object, it's a typedef for some primitive type :)

Answer (score 0):

I have thought about this also, though in the end I ask would it actually make me more productive. Objective-C seems to me to be a very pragmatic language, the features it has are real world useful, things like block are super useful, but features like namespaces and typed arrays in my experience not so much. I add a lot of NSAssert to my code to check stuff like that. Usually my mutable collections are contained within other classes and so I have a lot of control over what can be added to them, but maybe thats a pattern I adopt because I don't have typed collections?

Answer (score 0):

Well, technically you already can...

```
UIView *views[] = {one, two, three};  
NSInteger object = views[2];
```

Or, more usefully, you could use Objective-C++.