# How to use protocols with categories for NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, protocols, objective-c-category

I don't think I've found an example quite like my own on this site even though I'm sure this pops up all the time, and I just finished a chapter on this subject in [my book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/032188728X).

I'm not looking for anything complicated, but I just want to add some functionality to `NSMutableArray` for objects that are of a certain type because I don't want to subclass `NSMutableArray` because it seems too difficult, but I may change my mind about that.

**I want a category that offers `NSMutableArray`s that conform to the `NDVector` protocol the ability to do certain things like calculate the norm, rotate about an axis, etc.**

I've tried a couple things, and I'm currently thinking it should be something like this:

- Make a protocol: `@protocol NDVector <NSMutableArray>` and declare methods there
- Create a category `@interface NSMutableArray (NDVector)` that... also declares the methods?
- Implement the methods in that category's implementation `@implementation NSMutableArray (NDVector)`
- And finally, *somehow* instantiate an `NSMutableArray<NDVector>` (I'm coming from Java), object like this `NSMutableArray<NDVector> vec = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]`

How should I actually be doing this? Please don't just send a link, provide an explanation that parallels my methodology, but with the correct steps involved.

Comment: Why `<NSMutableArray>`?

Comment: Because I want my `NDVector`s to be mutable. Is there a better class I should be using for this?

Comment: You don't understand what that syntax mean in Obj-C, I think. Don't mix Java Generics with Obj-C protocols which are also denoted by < ... >.

Comment: @Sulthan I know that's not how it's done in Obj-C. That's why I'm asking how it is done.

Answer (score 2):

None of your current approaches are really the best way. I would suggest you create a vector class that just so happens to use a mutable array in its own implementation.

You could even have an `init` method in your vector class that takes an array.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand your question correctly. If you want to have some operations on an array of vectors, then you have basically 3 possibilities:

**1. Inheritance**

For `NSMutableArray`, subclassing is not really an option because it requires us to reimplement the array.

**2. Encapsulation**

The array is hidden inside (in the class extension) and cannot be accessed directly.

```
@interface NDVectorArray : NSObject

- (void)addVector:(NDVector *)vector;

//TODO: add the methods you want

@end

@interface NDVectorArray ()

@property (nonatomic, strong, readwrite) NSMutableArray *elements;

@end

@implementation NDVectorArray

- (void)addVector:(NDVector *)vector {
   [self.elements addObject:vector];
}

//add the methods you want

@end
```

**3. Category**

This adds only methods and contains no checks for object type.

```
@interface NSMutableArray (NDVector)

//add the methods you want

@end

@implementation NSMutableArray (NDVector)

//implement any methods you want
@end
```

**Summary**

In my opinion, the 3rd will be hard to use. The 2nd will be easy to implement and to use.

Comment: Subclassing a class-cluster is a terrible idea, and would indeed, not work in this case. So your option no. 1 should be deleted.

Comment: @LeoNatan That's not true. The possibility to subclass `NSMutableArray` is even mentioned in the class documentation. See https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html.

Comment: Did you actually read the documentation? "In a subclass, you must override all these methods. You must also override the primitive methods of the NSArray class."

Yeah, you can subclass. But you have to reimplement the entire functionality of `NSArray` and `NSMutableArray`. Great solution.

Comment: @LeoNatan I am afraid I was wrong. Unfortunately, I read only `NSMutableArray` docs, not the `NSArray` docs when the problem is explained. Class clusters are so terrible to use..

Comment: No worries. Please remove inheritance from your answer.

Answer (score 0):

If I follow correctly you essentially would like a subclass of `NSMutableArray` which (a) holds on instances of `NDVector` and (b) has additional `NDVector`-specific methods which operate on the array as a whole.

First subclass `NSMutableArray`, it is not hard and the code to do it and (a) can be found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5197446/nsmutablearray-force-the-array-to-hold-specific-object-type-only/5198040#5198040) - that code is designed to work for any type. You can specialise it to `NDVector` only, you may also want to add, say, `insertVector:atIndex:` and similar methods to avoid the runtime check present in `insertObject:atIndex:`.

Second just add your extra methods for (b) to this class.