# Objective-C: NSArray of Custom Class?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I am trying to learn `iOS`, I come from `Java` background where we can have lists/arrays of specific classes like

```
List<String> l = new ArrayList<>();
List<MyClass> l = new ArrayList<>();
```

Looking at `Objective-C`, I can make use of `NSArray` class to make `immutable` arrays, but how do I specify that this `NSArrray` is **strictly** of type `MyClass`?

Comment: You only put MyClass objects into it.

Comment: I get that, I was curious if we have something similar to `Generics` here

Comment: If you must, you can look at Swift.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, there isn't a built-in mechanism for specifying the type of objects put into NSArrays in Objective-C, but it looks like Swift does what you're looking for if that helps at all:

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH8-XID_172

On a slightly related note, there's a decent write-up here about enforcing inserting objects of only a certain type into a subclassed NSMutableArray and throwing exceptions if trying to insert the *wrong* object types:

[NSMutableArray - force the array to hold specific object type only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5197446/nsmutablearray-force-the-array-to-hold-specific-object-type-only)

Answer (score 4):

Now Xcode 7 supports some kind of generics for standard collections(e.g. NSArrays). So you can make an array and provide kind of storing objects like this:

```
NSArray<NSString*> *myArrayOfStrings;
```

Answer (score 0):

Sadly there are no generics in Objective-C.

Comment: Why? I hate the untyped nature of Objective-C. Swift seems to have introduced them though.

Comment: And I hate generics.  You spend much more time trying to work around their limitations than you'd spend debugging the very rare event of having the wrong object in the wrong collection.

Comment: @HotLicks Just use `<Any>` and the problem's gone.

Comment: For such a basic use-case there are only pros and absolutely no downside to using generics.

Comment: ..and the "event of having the wrong object in the wrong collection" is not rare at all for a dynamically-typed language like Objective-C.

Comment: I can't remember the last time that I had an instance of the wrong class in an NSArray that was supposed to contain instances of one class only, so I'd say it's rare, once you are past the beginner stage.

Comment: @gnasher729 bugs happen at any stage and if a language feature can avoid a trivial bug at compile-time I'm happy enough. After all many features are not intrinsically bad until someone uses them the wrong way, generics/templates can be evil but I don't think they are wrong by nature.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NSArray<MyClass*> *myClassArray` to declare an array of MyClass. If you want to make one of your own, you can do something like this.

```objectivec
// The only limitation is that MyGenericType must be an object.
// Exclude __covariant if you are doing something with the same interface in
// a different part of your code

@interface MyGenericClass<__covariant MyGenericType> : NSObject

// Your code here

@end
```

This usage of `__covariant` can be found in the interface for `NSArray` and more.

This is how it is used in the NSArray interface.

```objectivec
@interface NSArray<__covariant ObjectType> : NSObject <NSCopying, NSMutableCopying, NSSecureCoding, NSFastEnumeration>

// the code

@end

// A different part of the code using the same interface, so __covariant is excluded.
@interface NSArray<ObjectType> (NSExtendedArray)

// more code

@end
```

The reason that `MyGenericType` must be an object is because Objective C doesn't have an any type, so you use `id` in the implementation instead. But numbers can be expressed using `NSNumber`. You may also specify multiple `__covariants`, just separate them with a comma.

**Or you could look into swift**.