# Should we write `[NSMutableArray<NSString *> array]`?

Tags: objective-c, generics, nsarray, xcode7

Xcode 7 introduced generics. It allows for hint, like:

[image]

And allows for warning, like:

[image]

But it fails for many things, with no warning at all:

```
NSMutableArray<NSNumber *> *array;
array = [NSMutableArray<NSNumber *> arrayWithObjects:@0, @"", nil];
NSLog(@"%@", [array[1] class]);// __NSCFConstantString
array = [NSMutableArray<NSNumber *> arrayWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://ios.eezytutorials.com/sample-files/sample-array-plist.plist"]];
NSLog(@"%@", [array[0] class]); // __NSCFString
```

So typing the generic creation is kind of unreliable.

Question: should we use the unreliable syntax?

```
NSMutableArray<NSString *> *array;
array = [NSMutableArray<NSString *> array];
array = [NSMutableArray<NSString *> arrayWithArray:array];
array = [NSMutableArray<NSString *> arrayWithObjects:@"", @"", nil];
array = [NSMutableArray<NSString *> arrayWithContentsOfURL:url];
```

Or the simplified syntax?

```
NSMutableArray<NSString *> *array;
array = [NSMutableArray array];
array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:array];
array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"", @"", nil];
array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfURL:url];
```

I'm also concerned by the fact it is obviously not possible to give any compile-time guaranty of the return value of `arrayWithContentsOfURL` and `arrayWithContentsOfFile`. So will generics be always useless for those?

Comment: Why you want to loose the Dynamism of Objective-C if you are not sure the array will hold what kind of objects?

Comment: This answer can maybe help you : http://stackoverflow.com/a/5198040/3222713

Comment: Thanks @Pipiks, I understand it as to use the lightweight typing.

Comment: @AnoopVaidya Not knowing the type of thing an array will hold is not the general case and likely poor design.

Comment: @zaph: So suddenly from 2015 all the old code became poor!!! I meant we store different types of objects in an array, JSON returned NSDictionary, server error converted to NSError, our own error description as NSString...

Comment: In general "yes" that is poor design.

Comment: for `<NSString *>`, the items should be `@"..."`, for `<NSNumber *>` the items should be `@(...)`, that is why you get the warning, you add `NSNumber` in spite of you defined the array's item type is `NSString`.

Comment: @holex, that's obvious, and that's how I artificially made this warning to demonstrate the use of the syntax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're right, generics in Obj-C are imperfect, but:

- Some type checking is better than none
- Makes the code more self-documenting
- Future versions of Xcode could improve the type inference
- It already smooths integration with Swift -- something that it only going to get more important over time

Cons:

- Doesn't spot 100% of errors -- but does anything?
- Adds some extra cruft to your code

In summary: a slight improvement right now but makes your code more future-proof.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, one should use generics to provide further type specification information both to the compiler and for the developers.

Providing the type of object that an array will contain in the declaration is at a minimum a documentation gain and error checking is an additional benefit.

There is also the hope that type checking will improve in future versions of the compiler.

But in general mixing types in an array by accident has not been a problem, such mistakes tend to show confusion on the part of the developer. If I have an array of `Motorcycle` objects and add a `Juggler` object I either have a major design mismatch error or major confusion.

The best defense is good class and variable naming, not `array` but `motorcycleList` and `jugglerList`. Then if I have `motorcycleList addObject:juggler` it is quickly apparent there is an error right when the statement is being written.

This addition to the ObjC language is just a step in a progression of explicit specification:

```
id x = [NSMutableArray new];
NSMutableArray *list = [NSMutableArray new];
NSArray<NSString *> *stringList = [NSMutableArray new];
```

Comment: The documentation bit is so important that even if there was no checking, it still would be worth to use generics.

Comment: One implementation comes to my mind, assume I have an `NSView` and I loop through all the subViews, it may contain `NSButton`, `NSTextField`, `NSBox`, `NSView` etc. So in future how will be do this? Is this *really* a design flaw?

Comment: That is a poor example because they are all subclasses of `NSView`, it is an array of `NSView` objects. Throwing in an `NSNumber` would be inappropriate.

Comment: Sorry, but I like to know, how exactly it works. As you mentioned all are subclasses of `NSView`, then every object would be subclass of `NSObject` assuming `NSProxy` is not used.

Comment: Reductio ad absurdum?

Comment: Thanks, that helped me and will help others as well.

Comment: I've seen a lot of mistakes from people putting the wrong things in arrays. The most common in my experience is when there are models and view models (which is particularly bad because they often have many of the same methods so can often "work"). A particularly notorious example for one team was a system with both `Person` and `PersonRecord` classes. Someone would make arrays of `PersonRecords` and call the variable `people` and later maintainers would make exactly the mistake you'd imagine. Careful naming is so important, but generics would have saved us a lot of headaches.

Comment: @AnoopVaidya In the distant past in Objective-C `id` was used extensively as a type. The we started using specific type names and that vastly improved the code readability and error checking as well as reducing the need for casting. Now comes the ability to specify the types of array contents. If I create an array `NSArray<NSView *> *viewArray;` it is clear that I can send any `NSView` message to any object in the array without further type checking; that is a positive addition. It also tells me I can/should not add an `NSError *` or other object that are not at least subtypes of `NSView`.

Answer (score 0):

Because it does trigger the warning described in the question, using the constructor with specified generic type (`[NSMutableArray<NSString *> ...];`) is a better approach.

But we can assume that generics in Objective-C were introduced for transitioning to Swift, and in that regard, **using Swift directly is even better**.