# How to fetch data from sqlite db in list of objects in objective-c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, nsmutablearray

I want to fetch data from sqlite db in objective-c in the form of listArray(like in java android).

Here i have java class models for this

How can i convert these classes into objective c code confused in deceleration(.h) and implementation(.m)

Class 1

```
public class RecordingList {

public  ArrayList<RecordingItem> Items = new ArrayList<RecordingItem>();
}
```

class 2

```
public class RecordingItem {

public int ID;
public String RecordingTitle;
public String RecordingSubTitle;
public String RecordingAudioPath;
public String RecordingDuration;
public String RecordingNotePath;
public String Date;
public String Time;
public String PlayListId;
public ArrayList<RecordingAttachments> recordingAttachmentses = new   ArrayList<RecordingAttachments>();
}
```

I have try to get data in objective-c like this

```
- (NSArray*) getAllNotes
    {
        const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];
        if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &database) == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            NSString *querySQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                                  @"SELECT * FROM recordingItem"];
            const char *query_stmt = [querySQL UTF8String];
            NSMutableArray *resultArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
            if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database,
                                   query_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
            {
                if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
                {
                    NSString *name = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:
                                      (const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)];
                    [resultArray addObject:name];
                    NSString *department = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:
                                            (const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1)];
                    [resultArray addObject:department];
                    NSString *year = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:
                                      (const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 2)];
                    [resultArray addObject:year];
                    return resultArray;
                }
                else{
                    NSLog(@"Not found");
                    return nil;
                }
                sqlite3_reset(statement);
            }
        }
        return nil;
    }
```

But this is not what i want i want to get data in list of objects how can i do this?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

First off it is advisable to start with Objective C basics on your own. After that you'll be able to rewrite your Java classes in a couple of minutes.
 
What about data fetching, if you don't want to use [CoreData](https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/index.html) (which is recommended and handy, if you target only iOS), then you can use eg. [FMDatabase](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb) which is easier to use and hides all the native stuff you wrote here.
One more notice: you put `name`, `department`, `year` one after another in an array, create an ObjC `@interface` which will hold all the data:

```
@interface Data : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *department;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *year;

@end
```

and use it like that:

```
NSMutableArray *resultArray = [NSMutableArray new];
// fetch ...
Data *data = [[Data alloc] init];
data.name = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)];
// other fields ...
[resultArray addObject:data];
```

One more notice: [you can now create](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5197446/nsmutablearray-force-the-array-to-hold-specific-object-type-only) parametric arrays just like in Java.

Comment: @NisarAhmad the best thanks here on SO is voting answer up ;)