# Find NSMutableArray<ObjectType> ObjectType at runtime

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsmutablearray, nsarray

I have an `NSMutableArray` in which i want to add those objects which conforms the `ObjectType`. Is there any way i can get the `ObjectType` declared using light weight generics so when adding an object i can check whether the object is about to insert is `ObjectType`; if yes insert it else just forget it.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you please explain your question more in detail?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking but this [NSMutableArray - force the array to hold specific object type only](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5197446/nsmutablearray-force-the-array-to-hold-specific-object-type-only) might help you.

Answer (score 0):

In Objective-C all type analysis is done at runtime and only at runtime. (The compiler gives *warnings* at compile time, but the produced code is bit-identical to  code with any other object type.) The lightweight generics are for Swift. We didn't need that in the past 30 years. (Wow, this is really long in computer sciences.)

So, any code related to the mutable array with or without type specifier is identical. For Objective-C a static type information is the wrong thing. Even there would be a way to do that, it would be anticonceptual.

So: No.

Why do you want to do that? Don't do it.

Comment: Let say i have different arrays for each type which holds thousands of objects each. I was think about to reduce the computation power by getting rid of introspection each time.

Comment: I do not understand, why you need "introspection" each time. If you want to do some specific depending on the type, make a protocol, add this to the classes in a category and implement the methods differently. However,  the runtime does introspection on every message dispatch. If you have a performance issue, make a new Q, show the code and one will help you.