# NSMutableArray with a specific class of object to be contained

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

Is there any way to specify what specific type of object can be contained within an `NSMutableArray`?

**EDIT** More specifically... *Is there a way to restrict the class that the object must belong to?*

Comment: An NSMutable array can hold any type of object and can hold different types of objects at one time.  Can you be more specific?  Do you need help adding objects of different types to the NSMutableArray?  Specifying an object type when getting it from the array?

Comment: Is there a way to restrict the class that the object must belong to?

Comment: Yes, use a Obj-C++ `vector<T *>`. Because ObjC is a dynamically typed language, it is extremely difficult to create something like this (but not impossible). This is because any object at any time can say it's another object, and the runtime has to believe it.

Comment: Could you just not add an object of a different type?  You cannot restrict an NSMutableArray to just one class.  Perhaps if you tell me more about why you need this I can help you find another solution?  Also, this may help: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Why is this necessary? You control what you add to the array, don't you? If you elaborate on why you need this functionality, I'm sure someone will be able to suggest a way to accomplish the same effect.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there any way to enforce typing on NSArray, NSMutableArray, etc.?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/649483/is-there-any-way-to-enforce-typing-on-nsarray-nsmutablearray-etc)

Comment: I want to make sure that if I pass off the source code to someone in the future, they won't make the mistake of passing the wrong object into an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you could always subclass `NSMutableArray` but as everyone else has said, it is hard to imagine a good reason to do this....

From **Subclassing Notes** in the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html) you would basically have to over-ride the following functions and check for the proper class:

- insertObject:atIndex:
- addObject:
- replaceObjectAtIndex:withObject:
- the primitive methods of the NSArray class

Comment: I ended up subclassing it and modifying all the methods as described here. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

You could check the class of the object before adding it to the array.

```
NSMutableArray *myArray = [NSMutableArray alloc] init];

if ([someObject isKindOfClass:[ClassYouWantInArray class]]){

    [myArray addObject:someObject];
}
```

Comment: You could add a class category too, to "addSomeObject" and verify it this way.